# Snake Game Reset Button not working?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Creating a snake game as a school assignment in Visual Basic. I've almost got i finished but running into some issues with the interaction of my Home screen form with my game/playfield form and my "You Died" form. I can get through one round of snake. My "You Died" screen pops up but when I click retry, it reloads the form in the state I left it or crashes. Same thing happens if I click my Home button to reopen the Home screen then I click play again and it takes me back to where I died.
**frmPlayField**

```
Public Class frmPlayfield


Public PFSize As Integer = SnakeHS.myPFSize 'To change the size of the play field depending on what difficulty the user selects.
Public PfPbSize As Integer = SnakeHS.myPfPbSize
Public tmrDiff As Integer = SnakeHS.mytmrDiff 'To change the interval of the timer depending on what difficulty the user selects.
Public scorePos As Integer = SnakeHS.myscorePos
'Food Creating and Grow Snake Variables
Dim randF As New Random

    Dim foodPointX As Integer = randF.Next(0, PFSize)
    Dim foodPointY As Integer = randF.Next(0, PFSize)

    'Play Field Variables
    Dim playMaxWidth As Integer = PFSize
    Dim playMaxHeight As Integer = PFSize
    Dim boxSize As Integer = PfPbSize                             'Size of PictureBox
Dim boxArray(,) As PictureBox 'PictureBox Array
Dim scoreSnake As New Label
'Snake Stuff Variable
Public playerScore As Integer = 0
Dim snake(0) As Point                                      'Snake array
Dim direction As New Point(1, 0)                           'Direction for snake movement

Public Sub Reset()
    Refresh()
End Sub
Private Sub frmPlayfield_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ReDim boxArray(playMaxWidth, playMaxHeight)
    For x As Integer = 0 To playMaxWidth
        For y As Integer = 0 To playMaxHeight
            boxArray(x, y) = New PictureBox
            boxArray(x, y).Width = boxSize
            boxArray(x, y).Height = boxSize
            boxArray(x, y).Top = y * boxSize
            boxArray(x, y).Left = x * boxSize
            boxArray(x, y).Visible = True
            boxArray(x, y).BackColor = Color.White
            boxArray(x, y).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            Me.Controls.Add(boxArray(x, y))
        Next
    Next
    Me.ClientSize = New Size((playMaxWidth + 10) * boxSize, (playMaxHeight + 1) * boxSize)


    scoreSnake.AutoSize = False
    scoreSnake.Width = 120
    scoreSnake.Height = 40
    scoreSnake.ForeColor = Color.Red
    scoreSnake.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
    scoreSnake.Visible = True
    scoreSnake.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    scoreSnake.Location = New Point(20, 20)
    scoreSnake.Text = 0
    scoreSnake.Name = "lblScore"
    scoreSnake.Font = New Font("Papyrus", 16, FontStyle.Bold)
    scoreSnake.Left = playMaxWidth + scorePos
    scoreSnake.Top = 10

    Me.Controls.Add(scoreSnake)

    snake(0) = New Point(1, 1) 'Creates snake head
    boxArray(foodPointX, foodPointY).BackColor = Color.Red
    timGameTick.Interval = tmrDiff
    timGameTick.Enabled = True
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Soundtrack_In_Game,
   AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
End Sub

Private Function createBox(x As Integer, y As Integer, bSize As Integer) As PictureBox
    Dim tempBox As New PictureBox With {
        .Width = bSize,
        .Height = bSize,
        .Top = y * bSize,
        .Left = x * bSize,
        .Visible = True,
        .BackColor = Color.White,
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    }
    Me.Controls.Add(tempBox)
    Return tempBox
End Function

Private Sub Died()
    If snake.Length > 1 Then
        For f = 1 To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
            If snake(0).X = snake(f).X And snake(0).Y = snake(f).Y Then
                My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Game_Over, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)

                timGameTick.Enabled = False

                Hide()
                You_Died.Show()
                My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
                Call GameMusic()
                Call Reset() 'removes all the controls on the form

            End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub GameMusic()

    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Pause_Music, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
End Sub

Private Sub Food()
    For i As Integer = snake.GetLowerBound(0) To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
        If snake(i).X = foodPointX And snake(i).Y = foodPointY Then
            ReDim Preserve snake(snake.Length)
            foodPointX = randF.Next(0, PFSize)
            foodPointY = randF.Next(0, PFSize)
            boxArray(foodPointX, foodPointY).BackColor = Color.Red
            playerScore += 10



        End If

    Next
    scoreSnake.Text = playerScore
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoundsAndMovement()
        For i As Integer = 0 To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
        boxArray(snake(i).X, snake(i).Y).BackColor = Color.White 'Loop to change the whole snake white
        boxArray(snake(i).X, snake(i).Y).Update()
        Next
        If snake.Length > 1 Then
            For i As Integer = snake.GetUpperBound(0) To 1 Step -1
                snake(i) = snake(i - 1)
            Next
        End If
    snake(0) = snake(0) + direction

    If snake(0).X > playMaxWidth Then
            snake(0).X -= (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If
        If snake(0).X < 0 Then
            snake(0).X += (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If                                                       'Four If statements to check if the snake has gone outside the play area.
        If snake(0).Y > playMaxWidth Then
            snake(0).Y -= (playMaxWidth + 1)
        End If
    If snake(0).Y < 0 Then
        snake(0).Y += (playMaxWidth + 1)
    End If



    For k As Integer = 0 To snake.GetUpperBound(0)
        boxArray(snake(k).X, snake(k).Y).BackColor = Color.Black 'Loop to make the whole snake black

    Next

End Sub



Private Sub timGameTick_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timGameTick.Tick
    Food()
    Died()
    CheckBoundsAndMovement()
End Sub

Private Sub frmPlayfield_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown 'Subroutine for direction
    Select Case (e.KeyCode)
        Case Keys.Up
            direction = New Point(0, -1)
        Case Keys.Down
            direction = New Point(0, 1)
        Case Keys.Left
            direction = New Point(-1, 0)
        Case Keys.Right
            direction = New Point(1, 0)
    End Select
End Sub


End Class
```

**Snake Home Screen**

```
Public Class SnakeHS
Public myPFSize As Integer
Public myPfPbSize As Integer
Public mytmrDiff As Integer
Public myscorePos As Integer
Private Sub btnPlay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click
    frmPlayfield.Refresh()
    If rbEasy.Checked Then
        myPFSize = 32
        myPfPbSize = 16
        mytmrDiff = 110
        myscorePos = 500
    End If
    If rbMedium.Checked Then
        myPFSize = 22
        myPfPbSize = 16
        mytmrDiff = 80
        myscorePos = 350
    End If
    If rbHard.Checked Then
        myPFSize = 12
        myPfPbSize = 16
        mytmrDiff = 50
        myscorePos = 200
    End If

    frmPlayfield.PfPbSize = myPfPbSize
    frmPlayfield.PFSize = myPFSize
    frmPlayfield.tmrDiff = mytmrDiff
    frmPlayfield.scorePos = myscorePos

    Hide()
    frmPlayfield.Show()





End Sub

Private Sub SnakeHS_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    rbEasy.Checked = True
End Sub
End Class
```

**You Died Screen**

```
Public Class You_Died
Private Sub btnHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHome.Click

    Close()
    SnakeHS.Refresh()
    SnakeHS.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveScore.Click

End Sub

Private Sub btnRetry_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRetry.Click

    Call frmPlayfield.Reset()
    Close()
    frmPlayfield.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub You_Died_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblScore.Text = frmPlayfield.playerScore


End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you to whoever can help me, unable to contact IT teacher for help.

Comment: `VBA` is a different language - suggest you edit the tags so your question hits the .Net people.

Comment: Also having problems with once my snake gets long, it starts to flash a little bit. I think it's to do with the code in my `CheckBoundsAndMovement` Sub

Comment: I rather think your snake flashes because you have to update so many picture boxes. WinForms' GDI+ isn't the fastest rendering mechanism.

Comment: Also, using the [**`Call` keyword**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/call-statement) is just unnecessary. This: `Call GameMusic()` is exactly the same as this: `GameMusic()`.

Comment: Inside `Reset()` you call `Refresh()`. Just so you know: that doesn't remove any controls, it just forces the form to redraw itself (see [**the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx)). -- As for your snake flashing, try removing the `boxArray(snake(i).X, snake(i).Y).Update()` line from your `CheckBoundsAndMovement()` method. It is just an unnecessary redraw of every picture box. A control will usually redraw itself automatically when you modify a property that changes it visually (for example `BackColor`).

Comment: You shouldn't use an array of PictureBox but simply one PictureBox. Inside the Paint event calculate the position and size of the blocks in the array. Then simply draw the rectangles: e.Graphics.DrawRectangle. Each time the form / picturebox is invalidated the picturebox will be redrawn. You can also trigger this yourself: PictureBox1.Invalidate(). To prevent flashing you can set frmPlayfield.DoubleBuffered = True.

Comment: I will remove any 'Refresh' commands. And I will remove the update command as well. My assignment is due in 14 hours and I don't have the expertise to change all my code to use just 1 picture box and paint rectangles. Is there any other way I can make my Retry button work?

Comment: To start with you must put some actual code in `frmPlayField`'s `Reset()` method. Though calling `frmPlayField.Close()` and `frmPlayField.Show()` should do the trick unless you store some game variables elsewhere.

Comment: Solved - Thanks Visual Vincent.

Comment: Glad I could help!